# same as VS the same as (What's the difference?)

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> A: I’ll have coffee. B: Same for me, please. VS The same for me, please.

> He gave me five dollars, same as usual. VS He gave me five dollars, the same as usual

1. 'same' goes toether many times with 'the'. Is there any spefic rule that we can omit 'the' when it's used with 'same'
2. Is there any case that we must omit the article 'the' when it's used with 'same'?

Comment: Have a look at some of the results from a Google Books search for [**"same" -"the same"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22same%22+-%22the+same%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03kmd7QRLQ35FDdqvuyL0AS4Fiv6Q:1621697683568&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqp_LSzt3wAhVq8OAKHYIKA-IQpwV6BAgBECE&biw=1504&bih=699&dpr=1.25) (specifically looking for instances of ***same*** that *aren't* preceded by the definite article). From what I can see, most results are actually references to ***same-sex marriages***, which collocation didn't even exist in English until a few decades ago. That's about the only case.

Comment: (Your first ***Same for me*** example is just an extremely relaxed conversational context where the speaker might even have thought he really was saying ***the*** - but it's so "unstressed" it doesn't get very clearly enunciated.)

Comment: In your two examples, omitting _the_ just makes the sentence less formal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Can you recommend any free text search engine?

Comment: Do you mean for searching in *your own* text files, or searching (publicly-available) texts on the Internet? If the latter, Google (Internet, or NGrams, or Books) is pretty much the only game in town now. I used to run [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) for the former under Windows (it allowed me to index files held in multiple locations, which was handy for searching thousands of movie subtitle files looking for some half-remembered fragment of dialogue).

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think Ngram will be satisfying at the moment.

Comment: Idiomatically, B can just say, "Same."